# Windows forms text box limit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to paste more than 600 numbers( like 29784250, 29784255, 29784260, 29784265..) in windows form text box But I am able to input only 225 numbers.. is there any limit for the textbox input? if so How do I need to change the limit

[image]

Calculated the number of characters that the text box is taking which is only 2249(for 225 nos)

Comment: You can set MaxLength property of textbox, But, I'm curious to know why you are not using richtextbox if you have such a long string?

Answer (score 2):

The number of characters that can be entered into the control. The default is 32767.

you can set it using **[MaxLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Comment: Calculated the number of characters that the text box is taking which is only 2249(for 225 nos)